# how to connect my Mongodb using mongoose and express.js to react frontend client?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I created a simple todo list app using the MERN stack. The app has a form where users can input their email, username, and a task description. This task is then displayed in a UI component.

However, I'm facing an issue where I'm unable to connect the backend with the frontend. I've spent hours trying to figure out what's wrong, but the problem seems to be that the useState hooks in the frontend are empty even though the backend has a JSON file with a lot of data. I've double-checked my code multiple times, but I still can't seem to get the data from the backend to show up in the frontend.

App.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import Task from "./components/Task";
import { CircularProgress } from "@mui/material";
import Registration from "./components/Registration";

function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [textInfo, setTextInfo] = useState([]);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/get');
      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await getData();
        const data = await response.json();
        setUsername(data[0].username);
        setEmail(data[0].email);
        setTextInfo(data[0].user_comment);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    };
    
    
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Registration />
      {textInfo.map((task) => (
        <Task username={username} email={email} text={task} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

from models file for the back end side this is the schema file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  user_comment: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);

module.exports = Comment;
```

now finally the main backend express.js file called server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const Comment = require('./models/Comment')



const app = express()
const port = 3001
const mongo ='mongo string'
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())


try {
  mongoose.connect(mongo, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  console.log(`mongo is running on ${mongo} !!!`);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
}







app.post('/user/post', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        
      const newComment = new Comment({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        user_comment: req.body.user_comment
      });
  
      await newComment.save();
      res.json(newComment);


    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error saving comment:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });

app.get('/get', async(req,res)=>{
    const commentsList = await Comment.find()
    
    res.json(commentsList)
})












app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: You are doing `const data = await response.json();` in your `getData()` but then you're again doing `const response = await getData();  const data = await response.json();`

Comment: i did that to convert it into json format after awaiting async operation